# Prove that if the # of vertices = # of edges, then # of vertices of degree 3 = # of vertices of degree 1

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

Assume $G$ is a graph where the vertices have degree $1$ or $3$.

Let $n$ be the number of vertices.

We know $n = |E(G)| = \frac12 \sum \deg(v) $

let $a$ be the number of vertices with degree $1$.

let $b$ be the number of vertices with degree $3$.

then $ n = \frac12 (a + 3b) $

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternately from Zubin's answer: You already showed $n=(1/2)(a+3b)$ i.e. $2n=a+3b$ so since also $n=a+b$ you get $2n=2a+2b$ and then 
$$a+3b=2a+2b,$$
which then gives $a=b$.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot the simple fact that n = a + b

Answer (score 3):

If there are $n$ edges, then the sum of the degrees of all the vertices must be $2n$.

But there are also $n$ vertices, so the *average* degree of a vertex is $2$. Since all vertices have degree either $1$ or $3$, $n$ must be even and the graph must have exactly $n/2$ vertices with degree $1$ and the same number of degree $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Following on what you did already, we have that $n = \frac{1}{2}(a+3b)$, with $a + b = n$. We get that $$ n = \frac{1}{2}(a+3b) = \frac{1}{2}(n+2b) \implies b = \frac{n}{2}$$.